# Subdirectory ignored in .gitignore whitelist

Tags: git

I am creating a git repository for my Linux home directory. I want to ignore most things except for files/directories that I whitelist. I have this:

```
# Ignore everything
*
# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!*/scripts/*
# the above line doesn't work, so this is a test:
!./scripts/*
```

But it's ignoring files that I add to the `scripts/` subdirectory. I've been adding things with `-f`, which is sub-optimal.

The answer to this question, [Git Won't Un-Ignore a Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694877/151841) , doesn't work for me.

Git version 2.1.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded

You need to explicitly unignore both the directory **and** its contents, or else the ignore rule negating the *contents* cannot match anything. First, unignore `scripts`, and *then* you can unignore `scripts/*`.

Here is the working .gitignore:

```
*
!.gitignore
!scripts
!scripts/*
```

That said, because you're unignore `*`, you can get away with just one rule, which unignores the path `scripts`. The second `scripts/*` is redundant.